# Remove international characters from slug - Almost done - Bit help

Tags: permalinks, urls, slug

I want to remove some characters from the slug, like "¿" that we use in spanish for opening a question.

If I go to wp-includes/formatting.php and in

```
function sanitize_title_with_dashes($title)
```

line 820 wp32
I add this

```
$title = str_replace('¿', '', $title);
```

just before
    $title = preg_replace('|%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])|', '---$1---', $title);

And it is working correctly. So when I write in the title "¿Qué tal?" the slug is "que-tal"

Now, how to do it with a function so I can use it via functions.php or via a plugin??

I am doing this but it is not working

```
function limpiar_slug($slug)
{
    $slug = str_replace('¿', '', $slug);
    return $slug;
}

add_filter('sanitize_title_with_dashes', 'limpiar_slug');
```

Any suggestion???

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't just pop filters onto functions, that's not how the filter system works, filters can only be attached to **filter hooks** and i'm quite sure `sanitize_title_with_dashes` is not a filter hook.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from my comment on your question.

The solution would be to hook your own filter onto the same functions `sanitize_title_with_dashes` does, in this case i think you're just aiming to hook onto `sanitize_title` as is done with `sanitize_title_with_dashes`.

Simply ensure you hook on after `sanitize_title_with_dashes`, which is hooked on at the default priority of 10.

Eg.

```
add_filter('sanitize_title', 'limpiar_slug', 11 );
```

No need to hack core files.

**EDIT BELOW:**

You could give some regex a try, here's a sample you can play with, code adapted from Adriana Villafañe's code in response to [Regular expression - any text to URL friendly one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051889/regular-expression-any-text-to-url-friendly-one) on StackOverflow.

```
add_filter( 'sanitize_title', 'sanitize_title_extra' );

function sanitize_title_extra( $title ) {

    $friendlyURL = htmlentities($title, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8", false); 
    $friendlyURL = preg_replace('/&([a-z]{1,2})(?:acute|lig|grave|ring|tilde|uml|cedil|caron);/i','\1',$friendlyURL);
    $friendlyURL = html_entity_decode($friendlyURL,ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8"); 
    $friendlyURL = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9-]+/i', '-', $friendlyURL);
    $friendlyURL = preg_replace('/-+/', '-', $friendlyURL);
    $friendlyURL = trim($friendlyURL, '-');
    $friendlyURL = strtolower($friendlyURL);
    return $friendlyURL;

}
```

Seems to do the trick of clearing up some unwanted characters, feel free to tweak, etc...

Comment: Your right, `sanitize_title_with_dashes` IS the actual filter I didn't thought of it that way, still it should be removing special characters by default

Comment: The problem has been acknowledged in [this Trac Ticket](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/9591).

Comment: Hi, I tried with that proposal, adding the 11 but still not working... BTW, there are more characters like copyright and registered, try to copy this in the title of your post:  Copyright © 2008-2011 ¿ ¡ holaos®

Comment: Have you tried removing the default wordpress filter and then adding your own the way you described it on your question? Like `remove_filter('sanitize_title', 'sanitize_title_with_dashes')` and then adding your custom filter with the `str_replace` like `add_filter('sanitize_title', 'limpiar_slug' )`

Comment: See update to answer.

Comment: Hi t31os, that script works but the problem is that with it, old entries cannot be accesed. I believe this is hardest that we thought at the beginning ! Thanks for the code, I need to think what to do, I should redirect dozens of entries...

Comment: I didn't thoroughly test the code, just long enough to see if it would remove non-alphanumeric from slugs, which it did do, i didn't notice any ill effects when editting test posts i created though. It was only posted to serve as an example anyway, i'm not writing your code for you... ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the function `sanitize_title_with_dashes` doesn't use filters (which is odd I think) so you won't be able to change it without hacking the formatting.php file directly :(

Comment: I have also tried with the function `sanitize_title` but doesnt work either. May be in another function??

Comment: I think the problem is the actual RegEx of the function, according to the functions documentation it "Limits the output to alphanumeric characters, underscore (_) and dash (-)" so in theory it should remove all special characters, maybe a bug?